# Angular 5 error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular

I need to set a cookie as below:

```
start: number;
...
this.start = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
...
if(!this._cookieService.check('confirmTimeoutStarted')){
  this._cookieService.set('confirmTimeoutStarted', this.start);
}
```

But I get:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Am I supposed to define the cookie variable type or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are stored in string format. It looks like the signature of the `this._cookieService.set` method accepts string, so you can do this:

```
this._cookieService.set('confirmTimeoutStarted', String(this.start));
```

Comment: But i need `this.start` to be a number so that i can calculate the timeout!

Comment: The property itself will still be a number in the rest of your application. String() does not mutate it, it will simply cast it to string for this particular method.